# Где правильно проверить был ли зарегистрирован юзер?

Tags: java, android

У меня такая головоломка.

Юзер, когда первый раз открывает приложение, попадает на первое активити и проходит регистрацию. Я локально сохраняю его ид и когда он открывает приложение второй раз, то java класс этого первого активити сразу проверяет был ли этот ид и если да то `intent`-ом открывает основное активити.

Все вроде логично, но у меня на этом основном активити есть кнопка при нажатии на которую юзеру должно открыться первое активити, и вот тут вопрос, потому что как я сказал на этом первом активити у меня стоит проверка которая видит, что юзер уже зарегистрирован и опять отправляет его на основное активити.

Как тут быть?

Мне нужно, чтоб и проверка была, и чтоб я мог нажатием на кнопку опять открыть первый экран...

Мне в голову пришла только идея создать впереди первого активити, сплеш активити в котором делать проверку был ли зарегистрирован этот юзер, если да, то он отправляется на основной экран, а с него уже может нажать на кнопку и вернуться на первый, а если сплеш активити сделает проверку и такого ид нет, то он попадает на первое активити.

Но проблема в том, что очень не хочется лепить еще одно активити...

**Что можно тут сделать?**

Comment: Может надо просто сбросить ид по нажатию на кнопку во втором активити?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во втором `activity` добавьте в `intent` любое значение , откуда нужно перейти на первое. Типа

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.thhis, FirstActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("value", "value");
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

В первом в `onCreate` вызовите

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("value") != null){
 //resume
}else{
  if (firstTime){
 //first logic
}else{
 //startActivity(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
}
}
```

Незнаю насколько это будет верным. Первое что пришло в голову. Хотя идея с проверочным скрином вроде нормально смотрится.

Comment: Да идея интересная на самом деле... Хотя я пока думал, слепил простую анимацию на сплеш активити и вроде не плохо смотритьсяю

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка ты хранишь какой-то флаг в SharedPreferences что пользователь зарегистрирован и по этому флагу проверяешь и перекидываешь на вторую активити. Так вот во втором активити ты можешь сделать так: чистить sharedPreferences и просто запускаешь через intent Первую активити

```
FirstActivity {

    if(sharedPreferences.userIsRegistered()){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
    }
}

SecondActivity {
    sharedPreference.setUserIsRegistered(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: Да но если я почищу преф то как я узнаю, что это тот же юзер, если он откроет приложение 2-й раз? или каждый раз когда он попадает на первое активити перезаписывать преф?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko ты можешь userId и userIsRegistered параметры оставить, а завести например параметр showRegisteredScreen и в зависимости от этого параметра плясать
    if(sharedPreferences.userIsRegistered() && !sharedPreferences.showRegisteredScreen()){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
    }
    
SecondActivity {
    sharedPreference.setshowRegisteredScreen(true);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class));
}